# Remove characters from string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string in the following format. Im trying to create a function in Java Script to remove certain charcters.

Sample String:

```
Var s = '18160 ~ SCC-Hard Drive ~ 4 ~ d | 18170 ~ SCC-SSD ~ 4 ~ de | 18180 ~ SCC-Monitor ~ 5 ~ | 18190 ~ SCC-Keyboard ~ null ~'
```

Desired Result:

```
s = 'SCC-Hard Drive ~ 4 ~ d | SCC-SSD ~ 4 ~ de | SCC-Monitor ~ 5 ~ |SCC-Keyboard ~ null ~'
```

If you notice above the ID'S for instance 18160, 18170, 18180 and 18190 were removed. This is just as example.  the structure is as follows:

```
id: 18160
description : SCC-Hard Drive
Type: 4
comment: d
```

So where there are multiple items they get concatenated using the Pike delimeter. So my requirement is to remove the id's from a given string in the above structure.

Comment: What are the requirements? Will that string change? Will the numbers always be the same? ie. 18***?

Comment: What defines the portions that need to be removed?

Comment: if they're all in the same format, i'd suggest running it through a regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method perhaps.

```
s.replace(/\d{5}\s~\s/g, "")
```

---

```
\d{5} - matches 5 digits (the id)
\s    - matches a single space character
~     - matches the ~ literally
```

Output:

```
"SCC-Hard Drive ~ 4 ~ d | SCC-SSD ~ 4 ~ de | SCC-Monitor ~ 5 ~ | SCC-Keyboard ~ null ~"
```

Also, note that `Var` isn't valid. It should be `var`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the replace function with following regex since number of digits in the ID field can vary.

```
s.replace(/(^|\|\s)\d+\s~\s/g, '$1')
```